# What are NAF, NAES on RAM?

Tags: memory

I have two DDR3 2GB kingmax RAM. In the details of on of them `NAF` has been written and in another one `NAES`. What do these words mean?

Also are these memories compatible?

[image]

Comment: Where exactly are these 'written' on the RAM?  Are you sure they're not just part of the model/serial number?  Can you provide a picture?

Comment: Since there are parts with NBF, the second letter likely identifies some sequence where less than 26 values are expected to exist. A quick Googling did not find any Kingmax DIMM datasheets (datasheets often provide information on how part numbers are generated), so such information might not be readily available. If you are especially curious, you could contact Kingmax's sales ([their contact page](http://www.kingmax.com/en-global/html/contact) gives email addresses).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I added a picture and another question, are these memories compatible?

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton I asked the question and I'll post if they response.